# Refelection Converting Property into another instance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection, properties

i am trying to "upcast" a Entity. The Entity B have just a few more propeties.

Entities:

```
public class A
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

public class B : A
{
    public String ForeName { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to conver the value of A.Name into B.Name programmatically. 
I´ve written a little function for that case:

```
public static T Upcast<T>(Type typeOf, Object obj) where T : new()
{
    var target = new T();
    var props = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
    var targetProps = target.GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        foreach (var tp in targetProps)
        {
           if (prop.Name.Equals(tp.Name))
           {
              var val = prop.GetValue(props, null);
              tp.SetValue(null, val, null);
           }
        }
    }

    return target;
}
```

In this case: my target is class B and my obj is class A

But it fires a Exception in the second loop:

```
var val = prop.GetValue(props, null);
```

The Exception "**Object does not match target type**".

i am calling the function on a normal way:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var a = new A {Name = "Smith"};

   var resp = Upcast<B>(a.GetType(), a);
   Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why do you want to do this through reflection, rather than having a constructor in `B` that takes an instance of `A` and initializes from that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `prop.GetValue(props, null);` with `prop.GetValue(obj, null);`

It gives me "Smith".

Answer (score 1):

You must call `prop.GetValue(...);` with the target object as argument, not with the property collection:

```
prop.GetValue(obj, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with .NET 4.5 you can write

```
var val = prop.GetValue(obj);
```

You are trying the read the value out of an instance of PropertyInfo class. But what you want is to read the value out of your instance of A.

Another hint, for cleaner code:
Don't pass the type of A as argument. If you pass an instance of A, your method can make obj.GetType().

But: why are you doing that???

Comment: This doesn´t work: 
Can´t resolve Method candiates are: 
GetValue(object, object[])

Comment: OK, then use prop.GetValue(obj, null) as supposed in another answer. GetValue(obj) is new in .NET 4.5